Build a tar of pip package in bazel
I am trying to build a docker image with bazel and rules_oci. I am trying to build a tar file of a pip package to use as a layer in the docker image. How can I accomplish this with  minimal custom code? I can use pkg_tar (from rules_pkg) to generate the tar file, but I don't know how to get the sources of a pip package
For example, something like
load("@pip-deps//:requirements.bzl", pip_deps = "requirement")
load("@rules_pkg//pkg:tar.bzl", "pkg_tar")


# Some rule that gets the list of all sources for numpy
pip_source_list(
  name = "pip_files_numpy",
  deps = [
    pip_deps("numpy"),
  ],
)

# Create a tar file from the sources
pkg_tar(
  name = "tar_numpy",
  srcs = ":pip_files_numpy"
)

I am open to using alternatives of pkg_tar
